# Azure App Service Reverse Proxy works only on port 80 http

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module, arr

I'm trying to configure Azure App Service Reverse Proxy to expose webserver in Azure Virtual Network to the internet and I had limited success - it's working when I'm not using encrypted connection between reverse proxy and target server.

Here is my currently working configuration:

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                
                <rule name="ForceSSL" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
                
                <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" value="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" /> 
                        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
            <outboundRules>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="CheckContentType">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^(text/html|text/plain|text/xml|application/rss\+xml)" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

applicationHost.xdt

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false"/>
        <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

IP Address of the server has been replaced by example.com

When I change web.config rewrite rule and `HTTP_X_UNPROXIED_URL` to https I get following IIS Error

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module                         ApplicationRequestRouting
Notification                   ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler                        ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler
Error Code                     0x80072f8f
Requested URL                  https://example.com:80/
Physical Path                  D:\home\site\wwwroot
Logon Method                   Anonymous
Logon User                     Anonymous
Request Tracing Directory      D:\home\LogFiles
```

This suggests, that for some reason it's trying to request https on port 80.

I tried to follow guide from here: https://www.patrickob.com/2018/11/10/adding-ca-certs-to-the-trusted-root-store-for-web-apps-hosted-in-an-ase/

I have added my organizations root cert to SSL certificated and added `WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES` setting.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES is only supported in an App Service Environment, its not supported in multi-tenant app services. If the endpoint on-premises is signed by a certificate not using a public CA at this time there's no direct workaround to make this work outside of updating the certificate or possibly writing a simple proxy app that can ignore SSL cert validation (I typically wouldn't recommend this option unless you do the cert validation yourself in code).